# Socket.io: 404 not found while connecting to socket server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io, angular7

I have `socket.io` server and client running on different server. Locally it is working perfect but same thing does not work after deploying to Heroku.

In browser:

> GET https://yoloapp-server.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MXRdrhz 404 (Not Found)

On Server:

> heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MXRf8AS" host=yoloapp-server.herokuapp.com request_id=551994a1-4256-45b6-a283-42c083ef4c75 fwd="103.6.33.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=606 protocol=https

I tried to run client on same server as well, still same error.
I also tried to set port as well which Heroku uses internally.
Tried `{ rejectUnauthorized: false }` as well. Nothing works for me.

EDIT:

Client

```
this.client = io(https://yoloapp-server.herokuapp.com);
```

Server(express):

```
var app = express();
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
var server = app.listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: You need to provide your client side script using which client makes connection with heroku server.

Comment: Can you share your scripts please?

Comment: Please see the edit